# Ability to have an array of both const and non const pointers

Tags: c++, constants

I am trying to solve a electromagnetism simulation with the below code. My Node class has a member function that takes the problem array, and does calculations based on adjacent nodes.

We have some constraints, to implement them I create those nodes as const. For example the x+ and y+ edge are held at 100.

Then when a const Node is asked to calculate a new value it simply does nothing, thanks to the below function definitions in the class declaration:

```
void iteration( Node* array);
void iteration( const Node* array) const;
```

The rest of the code is shown below:

```
#include "node.h"


int main () {
    int max_x = 10;
    int max_y = 10;

    Node* problem[max_x][max_y];

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < max_x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < max_y; j++) {
            if ((i == max_x) || (j == max_y)) {
                problem[i][j] = new const Node(i, j, 100);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Am I approaching this wrong? The error I get is:

```
assigning Node * from incompatible type const Node *.
```

Obviously because I can't make a const node not const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either remove `const` from new Node declaration:

```
problem[i][j] = new Node(i, j, 100);
```

or declare your Node array as

```
const Node* problem[max_x][max_y];
```

In general, `const <type>`  and `<type>` (and pointers to them) might be treated differently by the compiler, hence mixing them up is discouraged (you can force it, with unsafe const cast, but it's not recommended).